# MS Outlook email alert

Tags: notification, outlook

I have all MS Outlook notifications disabled (toast notifications) in order to not get distracted at work.

However I would like to receive a notification if an email meets certain criteria (based on title).

Is it possible to achieve, either by configuration or some add-on?

I'm using MS Outlook 2016.

Comment: "by configuration" (ie. [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185)) is off-topic here (better fits e.g. [SU]). SR is about recommending software. So the addon-part fits here. Criteria only need to be based on the subject of a mail – or do you need other criteria (eg. sender) as well?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'll try it on SuperUser as well.In my case filtering by Title is enough.